# What is the objective of Silvershard Mine?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

After waiting in the queue for a while I finally entered the new Silvershard Mine Battleground. The Alliance was already losing at this point so I didn't really get a chance to figure things out from the start and everything was very hectic.

I gathered that it has to do with the carts that spawn and moving them by standing in the circle around the cart, but what actually makes the cart move? How do you score points? I guess I am looking for a breakdown of the ins and outs of Silvershard Mine as there appears to be a lot more involved than a simple capture the flag.

Comment: Obviously, just like all questions about a game in a beta stage, the details to this battleground are subject to change. So for the time being, assume that this is only dealing with the current beta build 15913.

Comment: I am going to vote to close this question, as MOP is still in beta. This can be reopened once the game's been released on the 25th of Sept.

Comment: @JamesJiao http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/mists-of-pandaria-beta-play-ask-answer-win

Comment: @JamesJiao This question can be reasonably answered. It's asking what the objectives are of the battleground. This can be answered in the context of the Beta, and we can be reasonably sure that the battleground's rules won't change significantly by release. That said, there is always the chance that the answer will become outdated, but release is still a while away.

Comment: @Fluttershy - I'm confused, because there is a promotion going on, its ok to ask "too localised" questions?

Comment: @Jared It doesn't make much sense to me, either... But apparently we're allowing questions regarding beta content for Mists of Pandaria...

Comment: @Jared There was [some feedback before the promotion was launched](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/reflection-on-contest-frequency-and-possible-mists-of-pandaria-promotion) voicing similar concerns, but it's probably good to provide feedback on the question Fluttershy linked to now that it's launched and we're starting to see what types of questions are getting asked.

Comment: @JamesJiao I don't understand why asking a question about MoP (which is still in beta) is any different than asking a question about Minecraft while it was still in beta. Are we going to go through a couple of hundred questions and close the ones that were asked before the game went into "release"?

Comment: @Adanion I wasn't involved in dealing with any Minecraft beta question, so I really don't know what to tell you. That being said, if I had been involved, I'd have suggested closing them as well. Fluttershy has provided a link to meta regarding this, so I am going to leave it at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WoW Insider has [an in-depth preview of the battleground](http://wow.joystiq.com/2012/07/31/new-mists-of-pandaria-battlegrounds-silvershard-mine/), which gives details about how the battleground is supposed to work (in theory). As they  describe it:

> [T]he objective of the battleground is for each faction to capture and escort mine carts to depots at the end of the line, retaining control of the carts throughout their jouney from the central depot to their destination.

And:

> Your team earns points for controlling carts over time, with a larger number of points for carts that land in the depot when under their control.

To move carts, you need to first capture them:

> Once the carts spawn, you need to capture them. This is done not by clicking with a capture timer like the flags in Arathi Basin but by fighting in proximity to the carts, like the towers in Eye of the Storm.

Then, they'll move along predetermined paths, determined by what crossroads your faction controls:

> Last, the two yellow markers are the two crossroads. This is where players can choose to alter the direction of the mine carts. Capturing the crossroads causes the arrow to flip around and change direction, sending the cart where it's pointing.